# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.lucene.codecs.PostingsFormat

Tags: solr, solrj

I'm trying to implement an Java program using EmbeddedSolrServer and when I run my program I get an exception :

```
Jul 03, 2013 12:13:49 PM org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer <init>
INFO: New CoreContainer 2120829822
Jul 03, 2013 12:13:49 PM org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer load
INFO: Loading CoreContainer using Solr Home: '/home/usersolr/solr-4.2.1/indexation_test1/solr'
Jul 03, 2013 12:13:49 PM org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader <init>
INFO: new SolrResourceLoader for directory: '/home/usersolr/solr-4.2.1/indexation_test1/solr/'
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/lucene/codecs/PostingsFormat
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.reloadLuceneSPI(SolrResourceLoader.java:181)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.<init>(SolrResourceLoader.java:114)
    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrResourceLoader.<init>(SolrResourceLoader.java:231)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.load(CoreContainer.java:422)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.load(CoreContainer.java:405)
    at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.<init>(CoreContainer.java:189)
    at Main.Main.main(Main.java:35)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.lucene.codecs.PostingsFormat
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    ... 12 more
```

Have someone already met this exception ? 
In witch JAR file can found the PostingsFormat class ?

**Edit (Solved):**

If you're like me and you don't know exactly where to find some jars you need, it's possible to find some jars files under these paths :

- solr-X.X.X/example/solr-webapp/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/
- solr-X.X.X/example/lib (particularly : servlet-api-X.X.jar)

Hope it helps !

Thank Marvin Emil Brach & Jayendra

Corentin

Comment: lucene-core-4.2.0.jar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the lucene-core-X.X.X jar to the class.
Also, if you have download Solr you would have all the required lucene jars in the lib folder which you can check for any class not found exception.

Comment: Thanks Jayendra, it works with this jar. I've got other exception but I'll find the solution thanks to your advice, I'll check the "lib" folder.